# Good EV3 iBook for programming or building

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, ev3-g

I am a participant in a Lego mind storms competition soon using EV3. I would like to know if there are good, free iBooks for me to download (PDF or iBook from the apple iBook store). 
Preferably the book should be about using EV3-G or building playing field style robots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer is google: FLL EV3 PDF

EV3 and PDF are obvious. FLL is short for FIRST Lego League, which may or may not be for "playing field style robots".

Clinics for coaches and kids at HighTechKids.org use [FLL Programming 101](http://home.earthlink.net/~dfrevert/fll/fll_programming_101_ev3_on_nxt.pdf) as a starting point.

The EV3 is new enough, that some of the best programming advice for FLL is directed at the NXT.